# Unable to compute FREERADIUS CHAP response based on ID + Password + Challenge in Python

Tags: python, authentication, hash, freeradius

I'm struggling to compute the response hash based on the CHAP ID + Plaintext Password + Challenge Hash.

Following is my code thus far :

```
def computeResponse(id_hex,password, challenge):
    #id_hex_result = id_hex.encode("hex")
    result = id_hex+password+challenge
    print result
    response = hashlib.md5(result).hexdigest()
    print "Generated: ",response
    print "Captured : ef53ae181830c4822f14ca826054cc8c"
computeResponse("1","SantaCruzpass","c8ec74267d0bbff78fe49abf756c211d")
```

The response generated was different as shown below the results :

```
Generated:  e6d0a07960e4d15153caf37fd06cdc8e
Captured : ef53ae181830c4822f14ca826054cc8c
```

Generated hash is the response computed by the program while the Captured hash is the actual response hash captured during authentication between HQ and Freeradius.

Am i doing it wrongly here ? The CHAP Id captured was "0x01" which yields the hexadecimal value of 1.

Comment: anyone able to help out ? is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password is already in binary form.

Try the following:

Just binascii.unhexlify the id_hex and challenge and you will get what you need.

`def computeResponse(id_hex,password, challenge):`

```
id_hex = binascii.unhexlify(id_hex)
challenge = binascii.unhexlify(challenge)
result = id_hex+password+challenge
print result
response = hashlib.md5(result).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution is:

```
def check_chap_password(clear_text_password, chap_challenge, chap_password):
    chap_id = chap_password[0:2]
    check_chap_password = chap_id + hashlib.md5(bytearray.fromhex(chap_id) + password + bytearray.fromhex(chap_challenge)).hexdigest()
    return check_chap_password == chap_password
```

Example:

```
check_chap_password('hello', '2d8f0e32ee566a4f26a9dc46eefeafc0', '6db35db7cf22ecc964ccbb9e6fa8afef')
```